# What languages still start fast with larger amounts of code?

Tags: performance, compilation, scalability

tl;dr I want a rapid edit-compile-run workflow, but prefixing every single function call in "somenamespace_" is annoying.

One (debatable) advantage of C is that you can have separate compilation units. Large amounts of code can be compiled into objects, and libraries, which are much faster to link together than parsing any amount of C code. It can be slower to run, since inlining optimizations can't be done between compliation units, but it is very fast to link, especially with that ld.gold linker.

Problem being, it's C. Lack of namespaces, pretty much.

But even C++ doesn't (in practice) use separate compliation units. Sure you can, but for the most part it's about including megabytes of templates in header files. The whole philosophy behind "private:" is to pretend you have separated interfaces, without actually having them at all. So the standard practice in a language is important too, because even if I make my own isolated binary interfaces, if each implementation has to #include the same tons of code from third parties, the time saved in isolating them doesn't add up. C++ is kind of... featureful for me, anyway. Really, I just want namespaces. (And modules... sigh)

Languages like python, racket and java use partial compilation, which seems fast enough, but you still get slowdowns in startup for large projects, as they have to translate all that bytecode into machine code every time. There's no option (outside of writing a C interface) to isolate code in a way that's fast to combine with code that you are working on.

I'd just like to know what languages where large amounts of code can be concealed behind small, quick to load interfaces, so that compiling them initially might be slow, but then I can get a rapid edit-compile-run cycle as I work on parts of it. Instead of this python hack, where I change something in the progress displayer, and then have to sit there staring at it as it loads the standard library, and then loads the database code, and then loads the web server code, and then loads the image processing code, and then sits there for another 20 seconds figuring out the gobject-introspection thing for some gui code.

It's not always obvious. I'm staring at D trying to figure out when it parses the code from dependencies when it recompiles stuff, without a clue. Go seems to just slap all the code together (including dependencies!) into a single compilation unit, but maybe I'm wrong there? And I don't think Nim regenerates all the generated C every compile, but maybe it does? Rust uses separate compliation units (I think) but it's still slow as heck to compile! And python really does compile fast, so it's only once my projects start getting big and successful that I start getting tripped up by it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't learned the other languages you mentioned such as Rust, D, or Python. When you compile a Nim program, it creates a folder called nimcache. That contains all the .c and .o files. If you make a change to the Nim program and recompile, it tries to reuse the files in that nimcache folder. The files have a .c and .o extension.